# Autohotkey: Paste/write a simple line of Arabic text with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: autohotkey, paste, arabic

I am writing this script to past fixed arabic name to file

```
; The following line defines the hotkey as WINKEY + 1 and sends the text "ملف جديد":

#1::SendInput, ملف جديد
```

The code is running but the arabic characters are not pasted as arabic. It shows different characters as follow `"Ù…Ù„Ù Ø¬Ø¯ÙŠØ¯"`

Am i missing something or the Autohotkey does not work with arabic characters or i need a different script?

Comment: **[Why are the non-ASCII characters in my script displaying or sending incorrectly?](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/FAQ.htm#nonascii)**